# How to include input data from HTML page into Parameters in URL?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

I am doing a BMR Calulcator + Calorie counter, and my first page is where user input their info like height/age/gender, and I need to display these results on my 2nd page.

Currently, I am able to display gender=male/female on the second page. I am also able to display Height/Age/Weight if I include them into the URL.

Eg:`xxx.html?gender=female+height=100+age=100` , and it will print out on the page as `Gender=Female Height=100 Age=100`

But, I am unable to get the userAge/Weight/Height into the URL.

FIRST PAGE JS:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/fpnrh

SECOND PAGE JS:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/6bvcu

Comment: Can you post your Html code or working example codepen or anything? So can try!